# Is there a way to prevent/detect DOM Clobbering in the browser?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, javascript

It is possible to clobber `document` attributes, e.g.:

```
<img name="cookie">
...
typeof(document.cookie)
//=> 'object'
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening, access the original value, or detect it has happened (beside type checking)?

Comment: Simple answer is no. Users have full control over the client. They can even make their own browsers. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? I highly suspect it is a client/server issue, and you really should be moving the items you want to protect over to the server.

Comment: I see, thank you. There isn't an existing issue I'm trying to solve, this is moreso just seeing if there's a better way to prevent DOM clobbering from breaking a security library. Looks like this case will just have to be dealt with from the library user's side